# SMTP emails not picking up the correct From name and From email

Tags: plugins, email, smtp

I am using an SMTP plugin to manage my emails in WordPress.
Previously I used a plugin called EasyWP SMTP. since it did not meet my needs I unstalled it and installed Post SMTP Mailer. now everything working fine. Even I can see email logs.

But except for one situation.
When I try to resend an email from the Email Logs interface. I receive the correct email.
But
From Name replace by : EasyWP (instead of my site name)
From email address : wordpress@mysitename.com (it should be admin@mysitename.com)

What should I do?
Where is this EasyWP name coming from? I checked every place. I can't find any place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled EasyWP SMTP or completely deleted it? If you've deleted it and it still shows the old from address, most likely some database entries are leftover. To fix:

1. Depending on how you've setup Post SMTP mailer, try changing the From address details in this [plugin's settings](https://ps.w.org/post-smtp/assets/screenshot-7.png?rev=1746638)
2. Manually change the From address in WordPress using filters in `functions.php`. See [method 3 at this link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-sender-name-in-outgoing-wordpress-email/)

Please note that this doesn't remove any database entries created by the EasyWP SMTP (if any).